# CentOS and Tomcat

Tags: linux, tomcat, centos, systemd

Recently I set up a CentOS server (CentOS is mandatory and was requested). This server should run an Apache Tomcat service.

The Tomcat server is running fine when I start it manually using:

```
[tomcat@ServerName]$ /mnt/data/apache-tomcat-9.0.33/bin/startup.sh
```

However, I want this service to start automatically. For this I created a `tomcat.service` under `/etc/systemd/system/`. Here is the contents of this file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Apache Tomcat Web Application Container
RequiresMountsFor=/mnt/data
Requires=pg-11.8.service
After=syslog.target network.target pg-11.8.service

[Service]
Type=forking

Environment=CATALINA_BASE=/mnt/data/apache-tomcat-9.0.33
Environment=CATALINA_HOME=/mnt/data/apache-tomcat-9.0.33
Environment=CATALINA_TMPDIR=/mnt/data/apache-tomcat-9.0.33/temp
Environment=CATALINA_PID=/mnt/data/apache-tomcat-9.0.33/temp/tomcat.pid
Environment=JRE_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.9.11-3.el8_3.x86_64

ExecStart=/mnt/data/apache-tomcat-9.0.33/bin/startup.sh
ExecStop=/mnt/data/apache-tomcat-9.0.33/bin/shutdown.sh
#ExecStop=/bin/kill -15 $MAINPID

User=tomcat
Group=tomcat

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This created service *won't start* the Tomcat server.

The binaries all (should) have read and execute permissions:

```
[admin@ServerName ~]$ ls -lah /mnt/data/apache-tomcat-9.0.33/bin/
total 824K
drwxr-xr-x.  2 tomcat tomcat 4.0K Feb  1 12:56 .
drwxrwxr-x. 10 tomcat tomcat 4.0K Feb  1 13:29 ..
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 tomcat tomcat  35K Mar 11  2020 bootstrap.jar
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 tomcat tomcat  24K Mar 11  2020 catalina.sh
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 tomcat tomcat 1.7K Mar 11  2020 catalina-tasks.xml
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 tomcat tomcat 2.0K Mar 11  2020 ciphers.sh
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 tomcat tomcat  25K Mar 11  2020 commons-daemon.jar
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 tomcat tomcat 203K Mar 11  2020 commons-daemon-native.tar.gz
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 tomcat tomcat 1.9K Mar 11  2020 configtest.sh
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 tomcat tomcat 8.5K Mar 11  2020 daemon.sh
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 tomcat tomcat 2.0K Mar 11  2020 digest.sh
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 tomcat tomcat 3.4K Mar 11  2020 makebase.sh
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 tomcat tomcat 3.7K Mar 11  2020 setclasspath.sh
-rwxrwxr-x.  1 tomcat tomcat  546 Feb  1 12:56 setenv.sh
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 tomcat tomcat 1.9K Mar 11  2020 shutdown.sh
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 tomcat tomcat 2.5K Feb  1 12:56 startup.sh
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 tomcat tomcat  49K Mar 11  2020 tomcat-juli.jar
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 tomcat tomcat 410K Mar 11  2020 tomcat-native.tar.gz
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 tomcat tomcat 5.5K Mar 11  2020 tool-wrapper.sh
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 tomcat tomcat 1.9K Mar 11  2020 version.sh
```

Why does the service not start either on boot nor on `sudo systemctl start tomcat.service`?

**Additional Infos** (several edit's since I missed some informations):

The `pg-11.8.service` is running a postgres instance. This service is running fine.

The `tomcat.service` is enabled:

```
[admin@ServerName ~]$ sudo systemctl list-unit-files | grep tomcat.service
tomcat.service                             enabled
```

Outputs of `sudo journalctl -xe -gtomcat`:

```
Feb 02 08:29:17 ServerName sudo[2022]: admin : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/admin ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/systemctl enable tomcat.service
Feb 02 08:29:22 ServerName sudo[2050]: admin : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/admin ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/systemctl start tomcat.service
Feb 02 08:30:44 ServerName sudo[2102]: admin : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/admin ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/ls -lah /mnt/data/apache-tomcat-9.0.33/bin/
Feb 02 08:30:57 ServerName sudo[2106]: admin : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/admin ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/ls -lah /mnt/data/apache-tomcat-9.0.33/temp
Feb 02 08:32:22 ServerName sudo[2135]: admin : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/admin ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/nano /etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service
Feb 02 08:33:11 ServerName sudo[2171]: admin : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/admin ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/ls -lah /mnt/data/apache-tomcat-9.0.33/
Feb 02 08:37:33 ServerName sudo[2289]: admin : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/admin ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/systemctl start tomcat.service
Feb 02 08:40:14 ServerName sudo[2422]: admin : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/admin ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/systemctl start tomcat.service
Feb 02 08:43:44 ServerName sudo[2758]: admin : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/admin ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/chmod +x -R /mnt/data/apache-tomcat-9.0.33/bin/
Feb 02 08:43:57 ServerName sudo[2772]: admin : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/admin ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/ls -lah /mnt/data/apache-tomcat-9.0.33/bin/
Feb 02 08:45:09 ServerName sudo[2804]: admin : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/admin ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/nano /etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service
Feb 02 08:48:32 ServerName sudo[2929]: admin : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/admin ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/systemctl start tomcat.service#
Feb 02 08:48:35 ServerName sudo[2934]: admin : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/admin ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/systemctl start tomcat.service
Feb 02 08:49:28 ServerName sudo[2972]: admin : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/admin ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/chmod +rx /mnt/data/apache-tomcat-9.0.33/bin/
Feb 02 08:50:07 ServerName sudo[2996]: admin : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/admin ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/systemctl start tomcat.service
Feb 02 09:07:37 ServerName sudo[3305]: admin : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/admin ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/nano /etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service
Feb 02 09:24:22 ServerName sudo[3616]: admin : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/admin ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/systemctl start tomcat.service
Feb 02 10:16:42 ServerName sudo[4504]: admin : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/admin ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/chmod -R +x /mnt/data/apache-tomcat-9.0.33/bin/
Feb 02 10:17:10 ServerName sudo[4541]: admin : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/admin ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/systemctl start tomcat.service
Feb 02 10:18:50 ServerName sudo[4585]: admin : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/admin ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/journalctl -gtomcat
Feb 02 10:20:21 ServerName polkitd[787]: Operator of unix-process:4669:747136 FAILED to authenticate to gain authorization for action org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units for system-bus-name::1.182 [systemctl start tomcat.service] (owned by unix-user:tomcat)
Feb 02 10:23:47 ServerName sudo[4825]: admin : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/admin ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/ls -lah /mnt/data/apache-tomcat-9.0.33/logs/
Feb 02 10:23:58 ServerName sudo[4838]: admin : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/admin ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/watch tail -n 60 /mnt/data/apache-tomcat-9.0.33/logs/catalina.out
Feb 02 10:24:07 ServerName sudo[4847]: admin : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/admin ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/watch tail -n 32 /mnt/data/apache-tomcat-9.0.33/logs/catalina.out
Feb 02 10:24:32 ServerName sudo[4885]: admin : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/admin ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/systemctl start tomcat.service
Feb 02 10:42:28 ServerName sudo[6320]: admin : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/admin ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/journalctl -xe -gtomcat
Feb 02 11:03:27 ServerName sudo[8088]: admin : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/admin ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/journalctl -xe -gtomcat
Feb 02 11:03:40 ServerName sudo[8106]: admin : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/admin ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/journalctl -xe -gtomcat
```

Executing `sudo systemctl start tomcat.service`, does simply nothing. It shows up in `htop`, but no message is being displayed.

Comment: what happens when you call `system start tomcat.service`? any messages on the console? if you have no messages try running `journalctl -xe` and check the last entries

Comment: Calling `system start tomcat.service` does nothing. It waits and then cancels. `sudo journalctl -xe -gtomcat` just dumps all failed attempts in starting tomcat

Comment: and there is no message why it fails?

Comment: No, nothing. I'll try to append the dumps in the OP

Comment: what do you mean `but no message is being displayed` ? where do you expect to see messages? is your server actually listening in any ports? and btw can you check in `/etc/polkit-1/rules.d` if you have any rules preventing your user of actions like this

Comment: Feb 02 10:20:21 ServerName polkitd[787]: Operator of unix-process:4669:747136 `FAILED to authenticate to gain authorization for action org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units for system-bus-name::1.182 [systemctl start tomcat.service] (owned by unix-user:tomcat)` points to rules.d usually

Comment: @ScharlaL: you should try to run it as user `tomcat` to check if there are no permission problems: `sudo -u tomcat -g tomca /path/to/tomcat/bin/startup.sh`